# Game Engine Remake - Trouble Choosing a Language /API(Java or Python)

Tags: java, python

The engine I've been wanting to remake is from a PlayStation 1 game called Final Fantasy Tactics, and the game is basically a 2.5D game I guess you could say. Low-resolution sprites and textures, and 3D maps for battlefields. The plan is to mainly load the graphics from a disc, or .iso (I already know the sectors the graphics need to be read from) and fill in the rest with game logic and graphics routines, and probably load other things from the disc like the map data.

I want this to be a multiplatform project, because I use Linux and would like for more people to join in on the project once I have enough done (and it's easy to get more people through platforms like Windows). I'll be making a website to host the project. Also, none of the graphics will be distributed, they'll have to be loaded from your own disc. I'd rather not have to deal with any legal issues.. At least not soon after the project is hosted on my site.

But anyway, here's my dilemma- I know quite a bit of Java, and some Python, but I'm worried about performance/feature issues if I make this engine using one of these two languages. I chose them due to familiarity and platform independence, but I haven't gotten too into graphics programming yet. I'm very much willing to learn, however, and I've done quite a bit of ASM work on the game- looking at graphics routines and whatnot. What would be the best route to take for a project like this? Oh, and keep in mind I'll eventually want to add higher-resolution textures in an .iso restructuring patch or something.

I'm assuming based on my results on Google that I could go with something like Pygame + OpenGL, JOGL, Pyglet, etc. Any suggestions on an API? Which has plenty of documentation/support for game or graphics programming? Do they have any serious performance hits?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have to say, the first thing that worries me about this is the legal issues. You want to remake an established game - do you have the IP or permissions to do so? Secondly, loading from iso's - With game distributing moving online and MMORPGs downloading gigabytes of graphics, why would you consider this? Thirdly from the end of your second paragraph I deduce that you are expecting legal issues. On the whole it sounds like you have issues other than technology that need to be addressed well before worrying about languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend going with PySFML, and, of course, Python.

If you do your Python programming correctly , and if you really are willing to fiddle with C or ASM Python plugins for faster computations, you shouldn't really have too much performace hits.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I wouldn't worry too much about language performance at this moment. If you worry about performance unnecessarily and choose the wrong/hard platform, your project will be dead before it started..because it will take it longer for you to produce something and harder to get other people to join your project.

Since your are familiar with Java & Python, I'll suggest do your project with [Jython](http://www.jython.org) or [JRuby](http://jruby.org). That way you get to write in nice and powerful language with the benefit of Java runtime.

By choosing to run it on Java runtime you get:

1. Multi platforms support, so this address your concern about linux/window platform.
2. Latest Java runtime is very good and in most cases the JIT can perform equal or better to natively compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day if you're passionate about the project and committed to getting the most out of the language you choose, the performance difference between java and python will be minimal if non-existent.

Personally speaking, the biggest challenge is finishing the project once it loses novelty and initial momentum.  I suggest you go with whichever language you're more passionate about and are interested in plumbing the depths of, or one that could boost your resume.

Secondly, as you mention you're hoping to attract contributors, you may want to factor that into your decision.  I can't comment much here, but have a look at similar projects with lots of activity.

Good luck!